# casting and shifting to from uint16_t to int16_t

Tags: c, casting, buffer, shift

I have a noob question about casting and shifting. I'm trying to store two elements of `uint8_t` from an array as a single, signed element in an array of type `int16_t`.  However my result is not correct, and I' don't know why.

I have this code:

```
uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
int16_t mp3_stereo_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];

for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE; i += 2) {
    mp3_stereo_buffer[i] = ((uint16_t)buffer[i] << 8) | ((uint16_t)buffer[i + 1]);
}
```

Comment: If both elements of `buffer` are `uint8_t`, `mp3_stereo_buffer` should be `uint16_t`. For `int16_t`, the most significant bit is the sign bit, and when set, results in a negative number.

Comment: @FiddlingBits so if I change mp3_stereo_buffer to uint16_t won't it remain unsigned?

Comment: @sam The context of your code is very limited, so it's difficult to understand exactly what your requirements and restraints are. To answer your question, though, C will interpret an `uint16_t` variable always as that, unless you cast it of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you can pack N `uint8_t` into N/2 `uint16_t` elements.

```
uint8_t buffer[BUFFER_SIZE];
uint16_t mp3_stereo_buffer[BUFFER_SIZE / 2];
```

Then you need to know if your data is little-endian or big-endian.

**For little-endian:**

```
for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE / 2; i++) {
  mp3_stereo_buffer[i] = (uint16_t) (buffer[i*2] | (buffer[i*2+1] << 8));
}
```

**For big-endian:**

```
for (i = 0; i < BUFFER_SIZE / 2; i++) {
  mp3_stereo_buffer[i] = (uint16_t) ((buffer[i*2] << 8) | buffer[i*2+1]);
}
```

p.s. If your data is in fact signed, then you can change the type and the casting to `int16_t` but beware that the way signed numbers are represented is not guaranteed to be portable.

Answer (score 0):

```
#define LITTLE_ENDIAN
int main()
{
uint8_t buffer[4]={0x15,0xff,0x63,0xee};
int16_t mp3_stereo_buffer[2];

for (int i = 0; i < 2; i += 1) {
    mp3_stereo_buffer[i] = ((int16_t*)buffer)[i];

#ifdef LITTLE_ENDIAN
    mp3_stereo_buffer[i]=(mp3_stereo_buffer[i]>>8 &0x00ff) | (mp3_stereo_buffer[i]<<8 & 0xff00);              
#endif

    printf("%x\n",mp3_stereo_buffer[i]&0xffff);
 }
return 0;
}
```